# Unable to install nginx-module-image-filter

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 server and got an error while trying to run `apt install nginx-module-image-filter`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx-module-image-filter : Depends: nginx-r1.18.0
```

Running `nginx -v`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: did You resolve it?

Comment: @Август No, but I found nginx working with image filters without installing this module on 20.04.